# Como subtrair indices extremos do mesmo vetor?

Tags: array, operadores

[image: A formula em questão]

Estou com dificuldade neste exercício, gostaria de saber como é possível realizar essa operação da fórmula

```
int main()
{
    int A[20], i, soma, j;

    cout << "Digite o valor do vetor A";

        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            cin >> A[i];
        }

            for (i = 0; i < 6; i--)
            {
                soma=A[i]+A[pow(i+i--)]
            }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça um loop até a metade da quantidade de elementos.
Pegue os extremos (em ordem crescente e decrescente) e some o quadrado dd diferença.
Ao final exiba a soma calculada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define N 6
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    int AN0], i, soma=0, j;
    cout << "Digite o valor do vetor A";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
        soma += pow((A[i] - A[N-i-1])), 2);
    }
    cout << "Soma: " << soma << endl
    return 0;
}
```

Note que em seu loop você parte de i com o valor zero e decrementa a cada ciclo, portanto ficará em um loop infinito pois sempre será menor que 6 (pelo menos até ocorrer um underflow).